# ResultSet looping less than number of rows

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I have a ResultSet which is returning 50 rows. I need to have a temporary table to which I insert these 50 rows so as I can perform queries on it.

There is no alternative for this so please don't suggest having a subquery or something else. A temporary table is needed.

So I am inserting the rows with the following method and apparently although I know the ResultSet consists of 50 rows, it is looping only for 13 times in the while loop and therefore when I go to extract some fields from this table, I do not have the required result.

```
public void insertValues(Connection con, ResultSet rs) {

    StringBuffer insert_into_temp = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();


        insert_into_temp.append("INSERT INTO SESSION.RETURNED_TICKETS (");

        for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
            insert_into_temp.append(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i)); 
            insert_into_temp.append(",");
        }

        insert_into_temp.deleteCharAt(insert_into_temp.length()-1);
        insert_into_temp.append(")");

        insert_into_temp.append("\nVALUES(");

        // number of place-holders for values
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
             insert_into_temp.append("?,");  
        }

        insert_into_temp.deleteCharAt(insert_into_temp.length()-1);
        insert_into_temp.append(")");

        while(rs.next()){
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(insert_into_temp.toString());

            pstmt.setInt(1, rs.getInt(Ticket.FLD_ID));
            pstmt.setString(2, rs.getString(Ticket.FLD_DESCRIPTION));
            pstmt.setInt(3, rs.getInt(Ticket.FLD_TICKETTYPE));
            pstmt.setString(4, rs.getString("STATE"));
            pstmt.setString(5, rs.getString("PRIORITY"));
            pstmt.setString(6, rs.getString("OWNER"));
            pstmt.setString(7, rs.getString("SUBMITTER"));
            pstmt.setString(8, rs.getString("TYPE"));
            pstmt.setString(9, rs.getString(Ticket.FLD_TITLE));
            pstmt.setString(10, rs.getString("PROJECT"));
            pstmt.setInt(11, rs.getInt("PROJID"));
            pstmt.setDouble(12, rs.getDouble("RELEASE"));
            pstmt.setTimestamp(13, rs.getTimestamp(Ticket.FLD_SUBMITDATE));
            pstmt.setInt(14, rs.getInt(Ticket.FLD_CUSTOMER));  
            pstmt.setInt(15, rs.getInt("ROW_NEXT")); 

            int success = pstmt.executeUpdate();

            if (success != 1) // if not successful
                throw new SQLException("Failed to insert values into temporary table for linked/unlinked tickets");

        }

    } catch (SQLException e){
        LogFile.logError("[Report.execute()] "+e.getMessage());
        LogFile.logError(insert_into_temp.toString());
    }
}
```

What can be the problem? I can't figure out why this is happening. 
Thanks

Comment: @Bernice..t means you need temp table?

Comment: You can narrow down your question by removing all of this insert code. Just leave print out from result set.

Comment: yes I am inserting into temp table. but it is this while loop that is looping only 13 times and only 13 rows are being inserted so I think this is the relevant code. the print out is just a select from where id in statement

Comment: Why are you creating your insert query within the loop? It's not like resultset metadata would change. And, the problem is probably not here but where you fire the actual query to get the resultset that you've passed in here. Post that code.

Comment: then it must be throwing exception

Comment: because I need to loop through the result set and insert each row to the table. what can I do instead of that? The actual query to return the result set is surely good because it works without running this part. I'm sure of it

Comment: and no its not throwing an exception cause I did a breakpoint after the method and the program stopped there so there should be no exception there

Comment: Create the query outside just once and execute within the loop. But, share the code that constructs this resultset first.

Comment: yeah youre right thanks :) done. really can't figure out this one though

Comment: What makes you so sure the result set has 50 rows in it?

Comment: because I ran the query on its own without the part I'm adding and it returned 50 rows :)

Comment: You are not closing your `pstmt`, so something might be leaky.

Comment: Also, for added performance, I would consider using 1 [batch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) rather than 50 individual statements...

Comment: using an INSERT inside a loop that is processing the result of a SELECT statement is extremely inefficient. The whole loop can be replaced with a **single** statement along the lines `insert into ... select ...` which will be *much* more efficient.

Comment: @beny23: even when using batched statements, the most efficient way is to do this in a single statement without any loop

Comment: What if you get rid of the insert and just increment a counter? Do you get 13 or 50 at the end?

Comment: yes I did that, it returned 13.. I will look into batches as soon as it works :)

Comment: Can you run some kind of SQL profiler to capture the statement that's creating the ResultSet?

Comment: actually there was an exception.. I debugged the program step by step and on the 13th time there was a -4220 error. Apparently eclipse debug is doing its thing :S

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: strictly speaking the OP didn't want any subclauses, though of course that would be the most efficient way of doing it, but I'm nitpicking :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood problem correctly, Instead of executing your query on every time use like this,

`con.setAutoCommit(false);
 while (rs.next()) {
// your setting values on prepared statement code
pstmt.addBatch();
}
pstmt.executeBatch();
con.setAutoCommit(true);`

Answer (score -2):

This doesn't answer your question, but it does show how you can avoid creating the prepared statement for every iteration. Instead you can prepare once and then bind different values on each iteration.

```
public void insertValues(Connection con, ResultSet rs) {
    try {

        StringBuffer insert_into_temp = new StringBuffer();

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        insert_into_temp.append("INSERT INTO SESSION.RETURNED_TICKETS (");

        for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
            insert_into_temp.append(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i)); 
            insert_into_temp.append(",");
        }

        insert_into_temp.deleteCharAt(insert_into_temp.length()-1);
        insert_into_temp.append(")");

        insert_into_temp.append("\nVALUES(");

        // number of place-holders for values
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
             insert_into_temp.append("?,");  
        }
        insert_into_temp.deleteCharAt(insert_into_temp.length()-1);
        insert_into_temp.append(")");

        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(insert_into_temp.toString());

        while (rs.next()) {

            pstmt.setInt(1, rs.getInt(Ticket.FLD_ID));
            pstmt.setString(2, rs.getString(Ticket.FLD_DESCRIPTION));
            pstmt.setInt(3, rs.getInt(Ticket.FLD_TICKETTYPE));
            pstmt.setString(4, rs.getString("STATE"));
            pstmt.setString(5, rs.getString("PRIORITY"));
            pstmt.setString(6, rs.getString("OWNER"));
            pstmt.setString(7, rs.getString("SUBMITTER"));
            pstmt.setString(8, rs.getString("TYPE"));
            pstmt.setString(9, rs.getString(Ticket.FLD_TITLE));
            pstmt.setString(10, rs.getString("PROJECT"));
            pstmt.setInt(11, rs.getInt("PROJID"));
            pstmt.setDouble(12, rs.getDouble("RELEASE"));
            pstmt.setTimestamp(13, rs.getTimestamp(Ticket.FLD_SUBMITDATE));
            pstmt.setInt(14, rs.getInt(Ticket.FLD_CUSTOMER));  
            pstmt.setInt(15, rs.getInt("ROW_NEXT")); 

            int success = pstmt.executeUpdate();

            if (success != 1) // if not successful
                throw new SQLException("Failed to insert values into temporary table for linked/unlinked tickets");

        }

    } catch (SQLException e){
        LogFile.logError("[Report.execute()] "+e.getMessage());
        LogFile.logError(insert_into_temp.toString());
    }
}
```